# How to mix divs/rows with fluid background colours

Tags: css, html, colors, background

I want some sort of function that will act like closing off a specific tag. I need to be able to colour the background of a fluid space, but its mixed in with a bunch of divs. How do I go about do this? Obviously closing the banner div where it is will make a mess of the rows/columns but I'm not sure how I should be doing it.

I've mocked up a pretty crude drawing to try and explain this a bit better.

[crude colour example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXb0W.jpg)

The white space above the blackline should be grey. This would all be very simple if it wasn't for the sidebar being there. I'm currently using Bootstrap 3.0 framework for a responsive design. Otherwise I would just make the sidebar absolute positioned and that would be that.

So how do I do this while maintaining a mobile friendly layout?

```
<%--<div class="greyBanner">--%>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
            </p>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Some heading</h1>
                    $PageSummary
                </div>

                <div class="1">
                    <div class="2">
                        <div class="3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="4"></div>
                    <div class="5"></div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        Important Update:<br/>

                        <p>Message and colour changed from the CMS</p>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <%--$SearchForm--%>
                    <select style="width:100%" id="e2" data-placeholder="Search...">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <% loop Doc_Resources %>
                            <option value="$Title">$Title</option>
                        <% end_loop %>
                        <% loop Doc_Forms %>
                            <option value="$Title">$Title</option>
                        <% end_loop %>
                        <% loop Doc_Policies %>
                            <option value="$Title">$Title</option>
                        <% end_loop %>
                    </select>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Resources</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">Forms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">Policies</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <%--</div> Close grey banner--%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps splitting the background into two parts, coloring the backgrounds how you'd like, then floating the right element *without* `overflow:hidden` on the container might work. That way the right element can be out of its container.

[**Rough Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gez3d/)

Comment: This won't work, as soon as the screen is resized it will blow it all out of alignment?

Comment: Yes, I don't mean that you change the width and height of the elements to percents like I have, I was demonstrating the technique of floating an element to reach outside of its parent's bounds